# Cisco Console Rollover Cable - RJ45 M/M Putty connection

Tags: cisco

Is it possible to connect a Cisco switch from ethernet to the console port with the cable linked here? https://www.amazon.co.uk/StarTech-com-Cisco-Console-Rollover-Cable/dp/B004Z9YG5W

If not, when do you use this cable?

I'm am trying to reset a bunch of switches with unknown config to their factory defaults. Or do you have to a serial version?

Thanks

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

No, this "light blue rollover cable" is for connecting one Cisco-type RS-232 device to another.  Most usually, one device was a PC serial port, with a great adaptor (9-pin female D-type to 8-pin female RJ-45), and the other is a Cisco console.

Given that most computers now don't have serial ports, you normally get a USB serial with a light blue cable on it.  (search for "USB Cisco console cable" .. it will be a USB-A plug at one end which goes into your laptop, and a RJ-45 plug at the other, which goes into the console socket of the switch.  Inside the cable is a USB-connected serial port, which shows up as `/dev/ttyUSB9` in Unix and `COM9` in Windows.  (Your `9` will vary.)

Although it's possible to find ethernet to serial adaptors, they are unusual and somewhat complex.

The USB version will be the cheapest and simplest solution.

NB: Do check the console port socket on the switches.  Some are not the familiar Cisco console RJ-45, it depends on the exact switch model.